# Dynamics 365 - Linq query with a not exists condition

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-365, not-exists

I have used the below linq query to translate a sql query with a not exists condition.

```
(from jdgAcc in srv.mn_jdg_accountsSet
where
!srv.mn_jdg_accountsSet.Where(jdgAcc1 => (jdgAcc1.mn_account.Id == jdgAcc.mn_account.Id)
&& (jdgAcc1.mn_contact.Id != jdgAcc.mn_contact.Id)).Any()
select jdgAcc.mn_account.Name)
```

But this throws an "Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method." exception.

Please let me know whats wrong with this query. I am not able to transform this into a list and get the count because of this error.

Thanks,

Sharmila.

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ for CRM implementation is limited, in the first place due to the fact these queries must be convertable to `QueryExpression` queries. Unfortunately LINQ for CRM does not support Not Exists conditions.